# Why Refreshview stops during the convertion of ienumerable to observablecollection in .net maui?

Tags: maui

I tried this 2 but same thing happen, I know its taking time to convert but atleast lets not stop the loading of refreshview

Option 1:

```
 Users = new ObservableCollection<User>(users);
```

Option 2:

```
 private async Task LoadUsers()
 {
  // some code here

         Users = users.ToObservableCollection();
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Users));

 // some code here
}


public static class EnumerableExtension
{
    public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> 
source)
  {
    
    ObservableCollection<T> collection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    foreach (T item in source) collection.Add(item);
    return collection;
}
```

}

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem or more code snippets (YouPage.xaml, YourPage.xaml.cs and view model)so that we can try to test on our side?

Comment: Why are you using ForEach though? You can just pass the enumerable into the Constructor of the ObserveableCollection and that would work